# Searching XPages event parameters

Tags: java, xpages, managed-bean, ssjs

I assembled this piece of code from parts all over the XPages community, you might recognise a few:

```
var submitId= param.get( '$$xspsubmitid');
var component:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspEventHandler= PageData.getComponentByClientId(submitId, view);
dprint("id= " + component.getClass().toString())
var params= component.getParameters();
for(var x:com.ibm.xsp.complex.Parameter in params) {
    dprint(x);
    dprint(x.getName());
    dprint(x.getValue());
}
```

PageData is a managed bean, and getComponentByClientId does exactly what it says; its code, for completeness' sake:

```
public UIComponent getComponentByClientId(String id, UIComponent root) {
    UIComponent component= new XspQuery().byClientId(id, root);
    return component;

}
```

And as for XspQuery:

```
package org.openntf.xsp.extlib.query;
```

I want to find the name of the current field that triggered the partial update, and the form it is in. Both elements, fields and forms, are internal to my application. Their names are put in two Event Parameters, like this:

```
<xp:this.parameters>
    <xp:parameter name="formName" value="#{javascript:compositeData.formName}"></xp:parameter>
    <xp:parameter name="fieldName" value="#{javascript:compositeData.fieldName}"></xp:parameter>
</xp:this.parameters>
```

The issue is: when I put this code in one of the page events afterRestoreView, beforeRenderResponse or afterRenderResponse, the name of the parameter is correctly printed, but the call to getValue() never returns anything! More accurately: execution of the code stops, I don't know the exact error yet (which isn't exactly accurate, I admit).

How can I fetch these parameters?

TIA!

Comment: I am a little bit confused: How do your *fields* do a partial refresh?

Comment: The best thing I can suggest is confirm via debugging that using $$xspsubmitid does actually give you the eventHandler of the component that fires the event. I think the submitId is actually the ID of the HTML form, not the component triggering the refresh, though I may be wrong. Also, the binding dynamic probably won't work in restoreView.

Comment: @Sven: my fields are like a radio groups, check boxes, dropdown lists, etc. that can trigger a partial refresh. All fields are dynamically created, their definition is inside a Notes document, and together they act like a form. There can be multiple forms on a page, and I want to know which of the forms triggered the refresh (so I don't have to recompute the fields on other forms).

Comment: @Paul: I'll check again, but I'm pretty sure of my case. I printed the component, its type clearly said com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspEventHandler. I added 2 parameters to the event handler, it prints the two, with the correct names. Other fields don't have these parameters, so they definitely belong to that particular event handler.

Comment: While I can see your problem (has something to do with JSF lifecycle and event handling of JSF), I can still not understand what you are trying to archive: Your fields have an Id ( your event handlers can have an Id too). So why don't you add the field and form name to the Id? this would allow you to identify the "target" everywhere in your code, not only in the ActionListeners...

Comment: Here is an example to use an  ActionListener: http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1368

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at code in Mastering XPages, the way to access the value of an eventHandler parameter within the eventHandler's SSJS code is just to reference the `name` property as a variable. e.g. `print(formName + ": " + fieldName)`

Comment: I wanted to avoid additional code per type of field (radio, check box), but I'm willing to try. I'll let you know what results I get.

Comment: Lo and behold... That seems to work, it prints form and field names. According to my logging, the event is executed after the afterRestoreView and before the beforeRenderResponse events. I suppose the value just isn't there when I try to get it from elsewhere. I'll add some code to the PageData bean so that it "knows" where I'm at.